# Parsing json And Update NULL for NULL Row via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm Parsing my json and Putting That to 3 New Column, `id2`,`awnser2` and`type2`, But Some Rows Are NULL, **How Can I Make a Condition To Update That Rows with Null?**(To Make`id2`,`type2`,`awnser2` = Null For Some Rows),
This Is One Row of My json:

```
[{"id":"26","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"3"},
{"id":"30","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"3"},
{"id":"31","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"3"}]
```

I mean, Forexample: My Secend Row IS NULL And Isn't Json, And I Have Error In my Output,
And This is My Code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","array");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }  
    $sql="SELECT `survey_answers`,us_id FROM `user_survey_start`";
    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
            $json = $row[0];
            $jason_array  = json_decode($json,true);
            // id2  
            $id = array();  
            foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
            $id[] = $data['id'];
            }
            $ids= implode(',',$id);
            $sql1="update user_survey_start set id2='$ids' where us_id=".$row[1];//run update sql
            echo $sql1."<br>";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

            // type2    
            $type = array();    
            foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
            $type[] = $data['type'];
            }
            $types= implode(',',$type);
            $sql2="update user_survey_start set type2='$types' where us_id=".$row[1];//run update sql
            echo $sql2."<br>";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql2);               
            // awnser2          
            $answers = array();
            foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
                    foreach($data['answer'] as $ans){
                    $answers[] =$ans['text'] ;
                    }
            }
            $answers= implode(',',$answers);
            $sql3="update user_survey_start set awnser2='$answers' where us_id=".$row[1];//run update sql
            echo $sql3."<br>";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql3);                                                                           
        }
    }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Question is not clear please try to explain in brief

Comment: I Updated My Question, I Can See Output Correct,But For NULL Row I Have This Error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp64\www\json\json.php on line 16`

Comment: first `var_dump($jason_array)` see what you get

Comment: I'm New In PHP And I Don't Understand Very Well, What Should I Do?

Comment: In while loop just do `var_dump($jason_array)` before `$id` comment the rest of code from `$id` to `mysqli_query($con,$sql3) `

Comment: YEs, I Have Output and IS Very Long, Forexample Some Lines: `C:\wamp64\www\json\json.php:15:null

C:\wamp64\www\json\json.php:15:null

C:\wamp64\www\json\json.php:15:
array (size=15)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '26' (length=2)
      'answer' => string '5' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '27' (length=2)
      'answer' => string '4' (length=1)
 
  `

Comment: As you shown your error Invalid argument for  foreach in line 16 mean `$jason_array` is not array but your `var_dump($jason_array)` showing is array. try one thing more `echo is_array($jason_array)`

Comment: Please Come To Chat .., I Commented `var_dump($jason_array)` and added `echo is_array($jason_array)` and i have 11111111111111111

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136212/discussion-between-sedric-heidarizarei-and-gaurav).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @gaurav, My Question Solved In Chat,
 `if(!is_null($json)){`

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","array");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT `survey_answers`,us_id FROM `user_survey_start`";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
$json = $row[0];
if(!is_null($json)){

$jason_array = json_decode($json,true);

// id2
$id = array();
foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
$id[] = $data['id'];
}
$ids= implode(',',$id);
$sql1="update user_survey_start set id2='$ids' where us_id=".$row[1];//run update sql
echo $sql1."<br>";
mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

// type2
$type = array();
foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
$type[] = $data['type'];
}
$types= implode(',',$type);
$sql2="update user_survey_start set type2='$types' where us_id=".$row[1];//run update sql
echo $sql2."<br>";
mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
// awnser2
$answers = array();
foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
foreach($data['answer'] as $ans){
$answers[] =$ans['text'] ;
}
}
$answers= implode(',',$answers);
$sql3="update user_survey_start set awnser2='$answers' where us_id=".$row[1];//run update sql
echo $sql3."<br>";
mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
}
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```